# Is it possible to listen to add a double click listener for the Package Explorer view? Eclipse Development

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible to do something in the title or similar? Is it possible to evaluate any double clicks that happen while a user is trying to develop in Eclipse?

I want to be able to evaluate the double clicks that happen in the Package Explorer and extract method names, definitions, and so forth.

Comment: What do you mean by 'extract method names, ...'? There may be a proper API for whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: For example, if a user double clicks a method in the Package Explorer View, I can tell which method the user clicked on and the method's definition (the code inside the method).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The first and foremost point of interest is in grabbing the Package Explorer view by using IPackagesViewPart along side its tree viewer.

Before you go out and try this though you must first import org.eclipse.jdt.ui.* and you may also need to configure your build path to contain the jdt packages

now the code:

```
IPackagesViewPart pvp = (IPackagesViewPart) getSite().getPage().findView("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer");
pvp.getTreeViewer().addDoubleClickListener(dblClckListener);
```

As for the listener itself you can grab the selection associated with the tree viewer and send it to a string. Then process the information however you see fit.

```
IDoubleClickListener dblClckListener = new IDoubleClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
        ISelection selection = event.getSelection();
        if(!selection.isEmpty()){
            myFindMethodFunction(selection.toString());
        }
    }
};
```